# How do I use textures in a .jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, lwjgl

I'm using LWJGL and Slick-Util. My texture loading works fine in Eclipse, but when I export it to a .jar, it gives java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found: res/test/texture.png

This is my texture loading code:

```
public int loadTexture(String file) {
    Texture tex = null;
    try {
        tex = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream("res/" + file + ".png"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int texID = tex.getTextureID();
    textures.add(texID);
    return texID;
}
```

Comment: use `getResourceAsStream` instead of `FileInputStream`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do not run the application from the right directory. For your code to work, you need to start the program in a directory containing the `res` folder.

Alternatively you can use

```
...
try {
    tex = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/" + file + ".png");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     ...
}
```

But in this case `res` folder needs to be added to classpath:

```
java -cp .;path/to/res;some.jar your.main.Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of getResource()/getResourceAsStream() with [OctoArcher](https://github.com/andronix3/OctoArcher)